# Can't this code calculate the result

Tags: untagged

```
Solve[ForAll[{n}, 
  d/2 n^2 + (a1 - d/2) n + (b1 q^n)/(q - 1) - b1/(q - 1) == 
   n^2 - n + 2^n - 1], {a1, b1, d, q}]
```

Running for over an hour without calculating the result

Always showing running

Comment: The equal coefficients of the corresponding terms in the equation can solve for four parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets first solve some problems where we give 4 different values of n and then solve for {a1, b1, d, q}:

```
eq= d/2 n^2 + (a1 - d/2) n + (b1 q^n)/(q - 1) - b1/(q - 1) == 
   n^2 - n + 2^n - 1;
Solve[eq /. n -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, {a1, b1, d, q}]
Solve[eq /. n -> {2, 3, 4, 5}, {a1, b1, d, q}]

{{a1 -> 0, b1 -> 1, d -> 2, q -> 2}}
{{a1 -> -(1024/81), b1 -> 2401/81, d -> 82/9, q -> -(2/7)}, {a1 -> 0, 
  b1 -> 1, d -> 2, q -> 2}}
```

Well, both cases have one common solution. Therefore, the guess is that  {a1 -> 0, b1 -> 1, d -> 2, q -> 2} may be a solution. Therefore, we try if this solves the equation for all n:

```
eq /. {a1 -> 0, b1 -> 1, d -> 2, q -> 2}

True
```

Indeed this solve the equation for all n.

Comment: How to use the format of Solve [ForALL] to calculate the values of these four parameters?

Comment: I do not think that MMA can do it in reasonable time. But I showed you how to proceed.